# Bathroom toilet has air bubbles when I shower

Tags: bathroom, toilet

Whenever I take a shower my toilet has air bubbles.

Do I need to snake my plumbing?

I live in a mobile home so do I remove the toilet to snake the main line or what do I need to do and how?

Comment: Do NOT remove the toilet to snake. I believe there are standards for mobile homes which would specify that they be constructed with a cleanout under the unit. I suppose it has a vent out the roof. First try running some water from a hose down the vent and see if this clears the vent.

Comment: The air bubbles in the toilet are from passing gas in the shower.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a roof vent is plugged or restricted. Run water from a hose into each roof vent and see if you can clear them. Have someone inside while running water into the vents to insure that if this would cause a water leak inside that you stop before doing damage.

Or run a snake down each roof vent. But don't drive the snake into the drain joint where the vent connects to the horizontal runs. You could damage the drain and turn a minor problem into a major one.